# Almost sure vs mean square convergence

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Define a sequence of events $\{E_n\}$ by 
$$E_n = \left(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}\right)$$ and define a sequence of random variable $\{X_n\}$ on the probability space $(0,1)$ equipped with Lebesgue measure by 
$$X_n(w) = (n^2 +n)^{1/2} 1_{E_n}(w).$$ 
Show that the sequence $\{X_n\}$ converges to zero almost surely but does not converge to zero in the mean square.

Comment: Your question was hard to read, so I decided to edit it. But maybe I have misinterpreted some of your notations. Please proofread my edit and make sure it is what you meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $w \in (0,1)$ arbritrary, then there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{N} < x$. Thus $1_{E_n}(w)=0$ for all $n \geq N$ and this implies $X_n(w)=0$ ($n \geq N$). Hence $X_n \to 0$ almost surely.

On the other hand, $$\begin{align} \|X_n\|_2^2 &= \int_0^1 X_n^2(w) \, dw = (n^2+n) \cdot \int_0^1 1_{E_n}(w) \, dw = n \cdot (n+1) \int_{\frac{1}{n+1}}^{\frac{1}{n}} 1 \, dw \\ &= n \cdot (n+1) \cdot \left( \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1} \right) = 1 \end{align}$$ which shows that $\|X_n\|_2 \not \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, i.e. $X_n$ does not converge to zero in mean-square.

Comment: thanx. God bless you.